# CSS only collapsible DIV

Tags: html, css

I have an example of a CSS-only collapsible div. But I want to change it a little bit to also include content in the header. How can I do that?

```css
/*
     CSS for the main interaction
    */

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}


/*
     Styling
    */

body {
  font: 16px/1.5em "Overpass", "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.accordion {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 0;
}

.accordion .handle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.accordion label {
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.accordion .handle label:before {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  content: "\f054";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: .58em;
  line-height: 1.556em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.handle label:before {
  content: "\f078";
}


/*
     Demo purposes only
    */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}

a {
  color: #06c;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.accordion {
  max-width: 65em;
}

.accordion p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>BJCP Style 26. Trappist Ale</h1>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1" checked="checked">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle1">26A. Trappist Single</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A pale, bitter, highly attenuated and well carbonated Trappist ale, showing a fruity-spicy Trappist yeast character, a spicy-floral hop profile, and a soft, supportive grainy-sweet malt palate.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> While Trappist breweries have a tradition of brewing a lower-strength beer as a monk’s daily ration, the bitter, pale beer this style describes is a relatively modern invention reflecting current tastes. Westvleteren first
      brewed theirs in 1999, but replaced older lower-gravity products.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle2">26B. Belgian Dubbel</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A deep reddish-copper, moderately strong, malty, complex Trappist ale with rich malty flavors, dark or dried fruit esters, and light alcohol blended together in a malty presentation that still finishes fairly dry.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> Originated at monasteries in the Middle Ages, and was revived in the mid-1800s after the Napoleonic era.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle3">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle3">26C. Belgian Tripel</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A pale, somewhat spicy, dry, strong Trappist ale with a pleasant rounded malt flavor and firm bitterness. Quite aromatic, with spicy, fruity, and light alcohol notes combining with the supportive clean malt character
      to produce a surprisingly drinkable beverage considering the high alcohol level.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> Originally popularized by the Trappist monastery at Westmalle.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

UPDATE: This is how it looks now. I want to place content in the header, the area where I now have the text "Belgian Tripel" but I want to have content there also. I want to replace the span element with a div element.

[image]

Comment: Can you make an example of what should be the output?
And send some Ale.

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: @AndreiTornea I have provided an example now.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubetI have provided an example now.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is provided natively without the need for css by the html details and summary tags.  I'd just use those, and put whatever html inside them that you want, and apply whatever css you want.

```
<details>
    <summary></summary>
    <!-- windowshade content here -->
</details>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean something like this:
you need to change your `Label Tag` to a `div` in your `HTML Code`. that's it!

```css
.accordion>input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100vw;
}

.accordion .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}

.accordion label {
  display: block;
}


/*
     Styling
    */

body {
  font: 16px/1.5em "Overpass", "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.accordion {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.content {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-top: 0;
}

.accordion .handle {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.accordion label {
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.accordion label:hover,
.accordion label:focus {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}

.accordion .handle label:before {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  content: "\f054";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: .58em;
  line-height: 1.556em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accordion>input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.handle label:before {
  content: "\f078";
}


/*
     Demo purposes only
    */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}

a {
  color: #06c;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.accordion {
  max-width: 65em;
}

.accordion p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>BJCP Style 26. Trappist Ale</h1>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse" id="handle1" checked="checked">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle1">26A. Trappist Single</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A pale, bitter, highly attenuated and well carbonated Trappist ale, showing a fruity-spicy Trappist yeast character, a spicy-floral hop profile, and a soft, supportive grainy-sweet malt palate.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> While Trappist breweries have a tradition of brewing a lower-strength beer as a monk’s daily ration, the bitter, pale beer this style describes is a relatively modern invention reflecting current tastes. Westvleteren first
      brewed theirs in 1999, but replaced older lower-gravity products.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle2">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <div>26B. Belgian Dubbel</div>    
    <div class="newDiv"> hier comes your Elements.</div>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A deep reddish-copper, moderately strong, malty, complex Trappist ale with rich malty flavors, dark or dried fruit esters, and light alcohol blended together in a malty presentation that still finishes fairly dry.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> Originated at monasteries in the Middle Ages, and was revived in the mid-1800s after the Napoleonic era.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="accordion">
  <input type="checkbox" name="collapse2" id="handle3">
  <h2 class="handle">
    <label for="handle3">26C. Belgian Tripel</label>
  </h2>
  <div class="content">
    <p><strong>Overall Impression:</strong> A pale, somewhat spicy, dry, strong Trappist ale with a pleasant rounded malt flavor and firm bitterness. Quite aromatic, with spicy, fruity, and light alcohol notes combining with the supportive clean malt character
      to produce a surprisingly drinkable beverage considering the high alcohol level.</p>
    <p><strong>History:</strong> Originally popularized by the Trappist monastery at Westmalle.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```